# Click selected combobox the first textbox.Focus() work Incomplete in C#

Tags: c#

Why textbox.Focus() work Incomplete? 
When I click selected combobox the first textbox must be focus but It focus just a moment and lost
I don't have idea why it be like this.

[image: my event]

It just have problem at combobox event. When I click button "CLEAR" it don't have problem. And when first text box text changed next textbox focus it don't have problem too.

What wrong with my code?

```
    private void combModel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gFan.Visible = false;
        gCom.Visible = false;
        gCon.Visible = false;
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;

        clr();

        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        string sql = "select * from model where model = '"+ combModel.Text +"'";
        string model, part, valchk, type;
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                model = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                type = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                part = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                valchk = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();

                if (type == "Compressor")
                {
                    gCom.Visible = true;
                    pCom.Text = part;
                    vCom.Text = valchk;

                }
                else if (type == "Condenser")
                {
                    gCon.Visible = true;
                    pCon.Text = part;
                    vCon.Text = valchk;

                }
                else if (type == "Fan Motor")
                {
                    gFan.Visible = true;
                    pFan.Text = part;
                    vFan.Text = valchk;
                }
            }
            timeStatus.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            gFan.Visible = false;
            gCom.Visible = false;
            gCon.Visible = false;
            btnRun.Visible = false;
        }
        conn.Close();

        if (txtFan.Visible)
        {
            txtFan.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtComp.Visible)
        {
            txtComp.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtCond.Visible)
        {
            txtCond.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use `TabIndex`?

Comment: Add tabindexing in sequence

Comment: Thank you, I already tried use TabIndex but It still not work. @RJay

Comment: what is timeStatus? Is that a timer? If so what are you doing in the tick event?

Comment: What app did you use to do the animation? My bet is `timeStatus.Start();` is the culprit. The reason I believe this is because the **TabStop** or **TabIndex** appear to be working, something else is doing it after. If it was a background thread (not on the main UI thread) I'd be less suss, but this smells of a Timer control used to do "something" most likely, a function on the Tick_Event interacting with other controls on the main thread.

Comment: I think it not about timeStatus.Start(); is the culprit. because I tried delete timeStatus out it still the same ( delete code start/stop and the event ) @JeremyThompson

Answer (score 0):

Many times (not always) the kind of wonky behavior you describe has to do with the processing of windows messages on the UI thread. Making calls on other UI controls in a message handler (setting Visibility but *especially* changing Focus) can interfere with the orderly execution of those messages.

It's good practice to allow SelectedIndexChanged hander to return immediately, and not attempt real work while the UI thread is blocked. The way to do this is to take the work and wrap in in a **BeginInvoke** using this syntax:

```
    private void combModel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ExecCombModel(); });     
    }
```

...where the real work is put in a separate method. (I named that method **ExecCombModel()** but it doesn't matter what you call it.) This function will execute immediately after the combo box change is entirely completed and drawn in its new state.

```
    private void ExecCombModel()
    {
        gFan.Visible = false;
        gCom.Visible = false;
        gCon.Visible = false;
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;

        clr();

        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        string sql = "select * from model where model = '" + combModel.Text + "'";
        string model, part, valchk, type;
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                model = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                type = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                part = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                valchk = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();

                if (type == "Compressor")
                {
                    gCom.Visible = true;
                    pCom.Text = part;
                    vCom.Text = valchk;

                }
                else if (type == "Condenser")
                {
                    gCon.Visible = true;
                    pCon.Text = part;
                    vCon.Text = valchk;

                }
                else if (type == "Fan Motor")
                {
                    gFan.Visible = true;
                    pFan.Text = part;
                    vFan.Text = valchk;
                }
            }
            timeStatus.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            gFan.Visible = false;
            gCom.Visible = false;
            gCon.Visible = false;
            btnRun.Visible = false;
        }
        conn.Close();

        if (txtFan.Visible)
        {
            txtFan.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtComp.Visible)
        {
            txtComp.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtCond.Visible)
        {
            txtCond.Focus();
        }
    }
```

I can't promise this will fix your particular issue, but it is good practice in general and has settled many, many similar issues I've dealt with in my own projects. Consider giving it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation. I already tried follow your suggestion But this method didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot! And like I said, I think I'm giving you good advice even if, unfortunately, it didn't work in this case.